# Directing non class callbacks into class methods

Tags: python

I'm trying to wrap an existing MQTT client with a helper class.

The functions defined by `paho.mqtt.client` defined as follows:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
def on_message( client, userdata, msg):
```

The wrapper class looks as follows:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

HOST = ''
PORT = 1883

class MqttHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.connect(HOST, PORT)
        # How can I direct those callbacks into the class functions?
        self.client.on_connect = on_connect 
        self.client.on_message = on_message 
        self.client.loop_forever()

    def terminate(self):
        self.client.disconnect()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        pass
```

The `paho.mqtt.client` `on_connect` property is expecting a function with a signature            of a non class function (without the leading `self` variable), how can I redirect those callbacks into my class functions?

Comment: have you tried `self.client.on_connect = lambda client, userdata, flags, rc: self.on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc)`?

Comment: `self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect`?

Comment: @luigibertaco thanks, add an answer so I could accept

Comment: Hi @aviran glad to help.

Comment: The best answer is @juanpa.arrivillaga 's

Comment: This is a subject worth studying. You seem to be yet uncomfortable with namespaces, classes, objects and their methods. Please find out what calling a method via an instance does to its parameters., i.e. `self` is added to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT***

Actually, the lambda function is not needed if you do as @juanpa.arrivillaga replied and follow @Pynchia 's instructions.

It will work if you do:

```
self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
```

I missed the fact that you were not doing `self.` in your question.

Thanks Pynchia your question, made me think better.

---

A lambda function would work on this case:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

HOST = ''
PORT = 1883

class MqttHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.connect(HOST, PORT)
        # How can I direct those callbacks into the class functions?
        self.client.on_connect = lambda client, userdata, flags, rc: self.on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc) 
        self.client.on_message = lambda client, userdata, msg: self.on_message(client, userdata, msg) 
        self.client.loop_forever()

    def terminate(self):
        self.client.disconnect()

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        pass

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        pass
```

The reason for the lambda function to work in this specific case is that `paho.mqtt.client.on_connect` expects a function with a signature of a non class function.

In other words, the expected signature for on_connect must be: `client, userdata, flags, rc`, but `MqttHandler.on_connect` signature is `self, client, userdata, flags, rc`.

The lambda in this case will allow you to invoke the instance method using it's own `self` statically, adding the other args dynamically.

Comment: Yes it would work. But: why is a lamba needed? Are you sure it's needed? Please do expound

Comment: Hi @Pynchia I've added some extra explanation. I hope it helps.